# Creating a crosstab query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, rollup

I have a MySQL table that tracks certain totals by both hour of the day and various locations. I am trying to create a query that will total not only each column, but also each row. The query I have so far totals each column, but I can't figure out how to get a total for each row as well.

This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT IFNULL(hour,"Total") as hour, SUM(location1), SUM(location2), SUM(location3), SUM(location4), SUM(location), FROM counts WHERE ay = 'AY1617' GROUP BY hour WITH ROLLUP) as crossdata
ORDER BY FIELD (hour,'8:00am','9:00am','10:00am','11:00am','12:00pm','1:00pm','2:00pm','3:00pm','4:00pm','5:00pm','6:00pm','7:00pm','8:00pm','9:00pm','10:00pm','11:00pm')
```

This is ultimately what I want the output to look like:

```
hour    location1    location2    location3    location4    totals
8am        4              3           2            1           10
9am        1              2           2            1            6
10am       2              3           2            3           10
totals     7              8           6            5           26
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, this is not a crosstab query. You aren't pivoting rows to columns.

I tried this query and got the result you want:

```
SELECT IFNULL(hour, 'Total') AS hour, 
  SUM(location1) AS location1, 
  SUM(location2) AS location2, 
  SUM(location3) AS location3, 
  SUM(location4) AS location4, 
  SUM(location1)+SUM(location2)+SUM(location3)+SUM(location4) AS totals 
FROM counts 
WHERE ay = 'AY1617' 
GROUP BY hour WITH ROLLUP;
```

You should really use the `TIME` data type instead of strings for the hour. Then it just sorts correctly.

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| hourt    | location1 | location2 | location3 | location4 | totals |
+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| 08:00:00 |         4 |         3 |         2 |         1 |     10 |
| 09:00:00 |         1 |         2 |         2 |         1 |      6 |
| 10:00:00 |         2 |         3 |         2 |         3 |     10 |
| Total    |         7 |         8 |         6 |         5 |     26 |
+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------+
```